# Grub menu won't show up after updating Ubuntu, can boot only into Windows

Tags: boot, grub2

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Toshiba P55 A5200 and everything was working perfectly. After I updated Ubuntu and installed a few applications GRUB menu won't show up and my computer only boots directly into Windows.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try reinstalling grub from within the live cd. Remember to replace 'sdX' with your desired boot disk/partition.

$    `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX`

$    `sudo update-grub`

If that fails try using boot-repair by following the steps below:

1. Boot into your live cd.
2. Download and install boot-repair (instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)).
3. Run from terminal: $ `sudo boot-repair`
4. Select 'fix recommended'
5. Reboot.

Comment: Which partition will that be? Is it the first /dev/sd1, or is it the one where I installed ubuntu (in which case is /dev/sd6)? Also, I noticed that my swap partition is saying 'unknown'. Perhaps it got corrupted during the update. Could it be a cause of this problem, and should I format it to swap again?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu as the only operating system? if so it would be safe to install grub to /dev/sd1. Sometimes swap will show up as 'unknown'. Try running $ sudo fdisk -l and see if it flags as swap.

Comment: I use it alongside Windows 8.

Comment: Boot into the live usb and follow the steps above regarding boot-repair. This wont mess up your windows installation.

Comment: I ran boot-repair and there is a dialog box with this: "WinEFI detected. Do you want to activate [Backup and rename Windows EFI files]?" Deciding to read before choosing anything, I see that a problem may be raised because of this and I'm afraid to do anything.

Comment: Never mind. I tried with "No" first and there was no changes. I tried with "Yes" and it worked, albeit with a few changes on the GRUB menu entries. Thanks a lot!