# Grub doesn't appear Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2

I have a problem when I start my computer. The problem is that when I start the computer, **grub** doesn't appear but it is installed. Firstly, I installed Ubuntu instead of Fedora 21 (I had Windows 8.1 but it was erased too). Then, when I started the computer, the screen shown a purple *frame* and a black square inside. I tried to 're-install' grub, with the following commands:

> sudo grub-install /dev/sda
>
> sudo update-grub

I followed these instructions: [Grub menu won't show up after updating Ubuntu, can boot only into Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433774/grub-menu-wont-show-up-after-updating-ubuntu-can-boot-only-into-windows)

At this point, I could see that when I started the computer, the screen shows a purple square, without the black *frame*. The grub config is by default.

Furthermore, I tried to re-install Ubuntu and I made an installation from scratch, but it doesn't work again. I have the same issue. I don't have more partitions, so I don't know what is happening. Also, I didn't find this problem searching in the web (maybe it is, but I didn't find it).

I'm not used to asking about doubts or troubles, so I don't know if it is the right place and if I have to put more info.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to boot into your BIOS and select which OS to boot in the (U)EFI menu. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported.

Comment: People keep advising to re-install or repair GRUB when this happens, but re-installing grub will not help (as you can clearly see)

Comment: See the "TROUBLESHOOT

YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS" section ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to create a separate /boot partition(if you have not done it already during installation) 
I think this can help you: [boot partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

Comment: No, no, no, it is an issue in the bios

Comment: yeah the /boot partition will take care of certain BIOS limitations which in this case may be the problem.

Comment: it is an issue with efi boot

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Actually, it is an 'issue' of UEFI, I tried to re-install using LVM partitioning and it automatically did a EFI partition, thanks for both, your links are nice!